# Microsoft Windows IIS and ARR

Tags: iis, arr

I am experiencing a problem with the configuration of Microsoft Application Request Routing 3.0 (ARR) that I cannot figure out why I cannot solve and I am therefore turning to the vast Internet for help.

The situation is that we have three IIS Server on our LAN with one site on each that I need to make available from the Internet. For that purpose, I have installed a Windows 2012 R2 server in the DMZ with IIS and ARR on it.

I have had the following three entries added to a public DNS ... all three pointing to my Firewall/DMZ

- public1.company.com
- public2.company.com
- public3.company.com

On the LAN I have the following three sites

- srv1.company.local/public
- srv2.company.local/public
- srv3.company.local/public

The concept is the users from the Internet should be able to access "server1.company.local/public" using "public1.company.com", but I have only been able to make it work when users enter "public1.company.com/public"

- public1.company.com <---> srv1.company.local/public

Using "URL Rewrite" in the IIS Manager I have create one rules per site:

- Match URL | Requested URL=Matches the Pattern | Using: Wildcards | Pattern: * | Ignore case
- Conditions | Match All | Input: {HTTP_HOST} Matches the Pattern | public1.* | Ignore case
- Action | Route to Server Farm | Action Properties | Schema = http:// | Server farm = srv1 | Path = /{R:0} | Stop processing

This setup work if we add “/public” when accessing the server on the LAN from the Internet.

But... I would like to get rid of the /public

Can anyone explain how this is done, if possible?

Answer (score 0):

You need to rewrite the public folder into the url in your reverse proxy rewrite.

Action | Route to Server Farm | Action Properties | Schema = http:// | Server farm = srv1 | Path = /Public/{R:0} | Stop processing